# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, pyinstaller

i tried to run a program and it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folderitasss\main\folderitoo\env\Scripts\process.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyaes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaes'
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i tried to uninstall pyaes and install it again
i also tried to uninstall pyinstaller and installit again
but nothing worked, can someone help?

Comment: I used `pip install pyaes` and `import pyaes` worked fine for me. What command did you run to install pyaes?

Comment: There is too little information to track down the issue. If I had to guess, you are mixing different Python installations. I recommend using a virtual environment to isolate your problem. What does `python --version` say? What does `pip --version` say?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thats what it says if i do python --version and pip --version

C:\Users\Administrator>python --version
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

C:\Users\Administrator>pip --version
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: but if i do py --version and py -m pip --version it says:

C:\Users\Administrator>py --version
Python 3.12.1

C:\Users\Administrator>py -m pip --version
pip 23.3.2 from C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

Comment: update: now when i run python --version it says Python 3.12.1 and when i run pip --version it says: pip 23.3.2 from C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `pyaes` might not be a builtin (as it has a [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pyaes/)).

You can install it using `pip install pyaes` in the command line (if pip is not in your path, try `python -m pip install pyaes`, or `python3`, `python3.7`, whatever your alias for python is).